# Can't align children of Rows by using the Align Widget and alignment property

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm having some hard time using `Alignments` in Flutter. I'm trying to create a disposable card.
I can't have the Image centerd and the icon placed on the top right corner.

[image: Can't center owl]

---

### Widgets Explanation

The `Card` consists of `Columns` and each `Column` has a `Row`

The `x` Icon is the first child of the first `Row`

I wrapped the Icon with `Align` Widget but it won't move on the right:

```
Row(children: [
     Align( 
     alignment: Alignment.topRight, 
     child: Icon(Icons.cancel),)
   ]
)
```

For the owl image i wrapped it inside a `Container` and used the `alignment` property to place in the the `Center`:

```
Row(children: [
   Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 150,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Image(
         alignment: Alignment.center,
         image: NetworkImage('https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/owl.jpg'),
            )
       ),
  ]),
```

Seems like no matter what I try on the layout it just won't move the objects inside the `Card`

---

Here is the `Card` Widget:

```
class CustomCard extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Card(
        child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Row(children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            child: Icon(Icons.cancel) ,
          )
         ]
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 8,
        ),
        Row(children: [
          Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 150,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Image(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                image: NetworkImage(
                    'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/owl.jpg'),
              ))
        ]),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

No matter what i try i can't have them placed correctly, have I completely missed the concepts of Align widget and alignment property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you needed to do was set the MainAxisAlignment to center for the Row. Please run the code below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: CustomCard(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomCard extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
        child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
          child: Icon(Icons.cancel),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 8,
        ),
        Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
          Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 150,
              child: Image(
                image: NetworkImage(
                    'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/owl.jpg'),
              ))
        ]),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, it was bugging me for a long time. You also remove the `Row` element from the `Icon` which i didn't thought of doing. Your example works perfectly. Thank you!